# Javascript button is not working with character array

Tags: javascript

OI have a field called qualification score to validate lead before converted when qualification score <=60.

But qualification score is a string it will be like 5%,60% or Something like x%.

So, I need to convert in to an integer and validate.

But I am getting this error:

> missing ; before statement

Please let me know where i missed it.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")}
String ourString = Lead.Qualification_Score__c;
String[] stringCharacters = ourString.split('%');
var child;
if(stringCharacters.length==1)
{
child = stringCharacters[0];
}
if(stringCharacters.length>1)
{
child =stringCharacters[0]+stringCharacters[1];
}
Integer d = Integer.ValueOf(child);
if(d<=60)
{
alert("Lead is not enough to qualify");
}
else{
window.open('https://cs57.salesforce.com/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL={!Lead.Id}&id={!Lead.Id}&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=VmpFPSxNakF4Tnkwd05DMHhObFF4TlRveE1Eb3hNUzQzTURGYSxoN2xDU05yM1FLVTZRb0x6bVJzaHMzLE4yWTBNVEJt&common.udd.actions.ActionsUtilORIG_URI=%2Flead%2Fleadconvert.jsp');
}
```

Comment: Is that qualification_score__c is percent field?

Comment: No it is a string field  and we are calculating through apex with our criteria

Comment: Is this JavaScript or Apex...? This isn't quite valid either way.

Comment: Sorry i am new to javascript i thought it works but i dont know where i missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a JavaScript button, it would be:

```
var score = parseInt("{!Lead.Qualification_Score__c}");
if(score<60) {
    alert("The score is too low");
} else {
    window.open("{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Convert, Lead.Id, [id=Lead.Id], true)}");
}
```

Use parseInt to read the value. Use URLFOR for the correct (domain-agnostic) URL.

Comment: Really you are life saver it works like as expected

Comment: @SantanuBoral JavaScript's parseInt simply reads digits until it finds a non-digit and stops. Feel free to read more on MDN [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 0):

**One** You have declared var child inside the for loop and using it outside the loop. So declare the variable before the for loop.

**two**
 Since the stringCharacters list will always have the correct value at index 0, you can directly use it instead of looping through it.

`var child = stringCharacters[0] ;`

Just doing this will serve your purpose instead of a for loop.

Comment: I am getting same error updated my code check once and let me know if i missed anything

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up apex with javascript.

There are no such String or Integer declarations in javascript.

> Since qualification score is a string it will be like 5%,60% or Something like x%, so you have to trim off the % from end.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")}

var ourString = {!VALUE( MID(Lead.Qualification_Score__c, 0, LEN(Lead.Qualification_Score__c)-1))};
if(ourString<=60)
{
    alert("Lead is not enough to qualify a lead");
}
else{
    window.open("{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Convert, Lead.Id, [id=Lead.Id], true)}");
}
```